# If $x$ is a square modulo two primes, then it is a square modulo their product

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

> $a, b$ be integers, $p, q$ primes. If $x \equiv a^2 $ (mod $p$) and $x \equiv b^2$ (mod $q$), then $x \equiv c^2$ (mod $pq$) for some  interger $c$.

I attempted to use Chinese Remainer Theorem, but did not get useful forms, so how to prove it?

Comment: Do you know the Legendre symbol?

Comment: You might want to specify that $p$ and $q$ are *distinct* primes.  Otherwise $a=b=1$, $p=q=2$, and $x=3$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @marwalix yes, but in my mind Legendre symbol ($q/p$) only applies to primes, not $pq$.

Comment: The Legendre is generalized into the Jacobi symbol that is multiplicative i.e $(\frac{pq}{a})=(\frac{p}{a})(\frac{q}{a})$

Comment: @marwalix If we are working with composite numbers, not only with primes, then the name is [Jacobi symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol). But even if we know that $\left(\frac{x}{pq}\right)=1$, this does not imply that $x$ is a quadratic residue modulo $pq$.

Comment: @marwalix If $\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{x}{q}\right)=-1$ then $\left(\frac{x}{pq}\right)=1$ but $x$ cannot be a perfect square modulo $pq$ because it is not a perfect square modulo $p$...

Comment: @N.S. You're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there exists an element $c$ such that
$$c \equiv a \pmod{p} \\
c \equiv b \pmod{q}$$

Then 
$$x \equiv c^2 \pmod{p}\\
x\equiv c^2 \pmod{q}$$